# Class 'Db' not found

Tags: php, sql, github

Tengo una script php que saqué de [Github - indieteq](https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class)

Para SQL, pero resulta que cuando la intento incluir en otros archivos, ya sea con include, require, los archivos no reconocen la clase Db 
Pueden ver la script php https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class
Mi código es este

```html
require('database.class.php');
$connection = new Db("localhost", "db", "root", "");
$id = uniqid();
$username = $_POST["regusername"];
$email = $_POST["regemail"];
$password = password_hash($_POST["regpassword"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$code = sha1(uniqid());
$nametag = rand(); 
$avatar = upload($_FILES["regavatar"]["name"], $id);
$connection->bindMore(array("id"=>$id, "username"=>$username, "email"=>$email, "password"=>$password, "code"=>$code, "nametag"=>$nametag, "avatar"=>$avatar));
$register = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password, code, nametag, avatar) values (:id, :username, :email, :password, :code, :nametag, :avatar)");

?>
```

Comment: está bien el require? en el repo dice `require("Db.class.php");`

Comment: Y la clase se llama  `DB`, [al menos en el repositorio](https://github.com/wickyaswal/indieteq-php-my-sql-pdo-database-class/blob/master/Db.class.php#L11). Revisa cómo se instaló en tu servidor. Si es así, deberías entonces poner: ¿¿`$connection = new DB("localhost", "db", "root", "");`??<-- OJO, según el código fuente la clase no acepta las credenciales en el constructor, deberías tenerlas en un archivo aparte. Observa el [método `Connect`](https://github.com/wickyaswal/indieteq-php-my-sql-pdo-database-class/blob/master/Db.class.php#L53) de la clase, lee las credenciales de otro archivo.

Comment: Probé poniendo db, Db. DB y ninguno hace ningún cambio. Lo último no entendí, soy un poco malo en esto, si me pudiese explicar para novatos, gracias

Comment: Ah ya entendí, pero no creo que sea eso, la última vez tenía problema de credenciales, que me ayudaste con ese error, y funcionaba bien, pero ahora que quiero usar la clase a través de include o require no funciona..

Comment: Primero, puedes depurar si el archivo se está importando bien. Haz esto: `$require=require('database.class.php'); var_dump($require);`  Si te muestra `int(1)` significa que el archivo se incluyó, si muestra `boolean (false)` o página en blanco o error 500, significa que no se incluyó. Pasada esa verificación, revisa que tienes un archivo con las credenciales, como indica la clase, y crea una instancia de la misma sin pasar las credenciales en el constructor... a no ser que hayas modificado la clase para que acepte esos parámetros en el constructor.

Comment: Esta clase `require('database.class.php');` no existe en el repositorio que pusiste, en el se llama `Db.class.php` por lo que esa línea debería ser `require('Db.class.php');`

Comment: Pero yo lo guardé con distinto nombre.

Comment: @A.Cedano Tal vez esa sea al solución, gracias por todo